# multiple parameters for psycopg2 where clause

Tags: psycopg2

I'm trying to run a `executemany` command but I can't get my table to update.  I was able to get it to work when I had one parameter in my WHERE CLAUSE, but now that I have multiple parameters the table fails to update.

```
cur.executemany("""UPDATE orders SET (invested_amount, ex_order_id, \
                time_acknowledged, execution_code) = \
                (%(invested_amount)s, %(instruct_id)s, current_timestamp, \
                %(execution_code)s) WHERE loan_id = %(loan_id)s and \
                requested_amount = %(requested_amount)s and execution_code = NULL""",
                order_list)
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Please edit the question to include that information.

Comment: I think it should be `execution_code IS NULL`

Comment: @bernie that was it.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
execution_code IS NULL
--             ^^
```